# ASP.NET Completely modular design - how?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modularity, modular

Technology: ASP.NET 4.0, C#, forms/mvc

I am a .NET web designer and I wish to create a modular based website for people, similar to what DNN does (but I want to create my own cut down version).

The idea is that I create a base website that can 'activate' features which the client needs (and has paid for).  These features may be used by many clients which require frequent future updates for all clients (so I wish to keep upgrade time down to a minimum).

For example, I upload the base web application using web deploy and it sets up the core database tables/views/SPs in the process.

Then I login into the website as developer and activate the out of the box features that I wish to permit the user to take advantage of.

The only way I can think of currently is via user control, resources etc..

But I need a little of your experience and advice over what the possibilities / dangers are....

e.g. images for an application e.g. blog, that I have activated for a client - how do I reference those images

e.g. Can user controls be dynamically added to a web application (which is pre-compiled unlike a website - it must be a web application since I am using web deploy).

e.g. Modification of web.config to add additional routing (doesn't matter if app has to go down to do this).

The idea is that I can upgrade websites features en-mass, rather than manually enhancing each individual website which given a certain amount of clients would result in an awful amount of time lost.

I do not have access to sharepoint (nor do I intend to).

Any advice on how to automate modularity completely via a front end in asp.net would be superb!

My main problem is how to reference files and resources outside of the websites directory and without using virtual directories (ideally - but open to suggestions).

Thanks,
Dan.

Comment: You may not be getting answers because this question is too big. I would suggest starting out looking at the source for DNN, and then when you get stuck ask a more specific question.

Comment: ...on the other hand, you might not be getting any answers because it's Christmas Day!  Merry Christmas.

Comment: Can't eat any more sweets!! oh my pooor tummy!

Comment: It's really a simple question though - how do you dynamically reference code in asp.net.  I can do user controls no problem - but WCF? EDM? Images? etc...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your idea sounds like an ideal scenario for WebParts. There are lots of resources on how to go about building a WebPart management structure from scratch. Then, in terms of your 'bulk update' facility, it would simply be a case of tweaking database entries that are used to configure which web parts a user sees.

I'd be interested to know what you decide to do.

Best
Ian

Comment: I decided to ditch asp.net 4.0 completely. I am now in the world of ASP.NET MVC 3.0 with C# 4.0 which is difficult but wonderful. I now use web.deploy to one click deploy with transformed web.configs. You can have small reusable section, reuse validation attribute (custom ones too). It's all fantastic! Take a look at mvc - read the vids and look through the tutorials at asp.net.  Also to get the modularity I am now looking into NuGet for a VS integrated package manager that I can create packages for.

Comment: That's fantastic Dan, glad it's all going well and thank you for feeding back to me. MVC is indeed a brilliant way of working and it's great you've found a suitable solution. All the best.

Comment: You're very welcome.  For some extra info, MVC 3 doesn't seem to support multi-project areas but I guess I can cope with a combination of areas and nu-get to get the job done.  Multi-project support was around in MVC 2 - pity they sometimes seem to drop things.  Glad I hadn't invested time with mutli-projects :D

Answer (score 0):

Try a Multi-Tenancy Architecture as you can find some good info here :

http://codeofrob.com/category/10.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/search.aspx?q=Multi-tenant+ASP.NET+MVC+%E2%80%93&o=Relevance

Comment: THanks for the answer - I've decided to ditch asp.net web forms and move to MVC3. In MVC you can split applications into "Areas" to keep things portable as possible.  That combined with NuGet has been super.  Also being able to use partial views, custom HTML helpers and redefining your own input controls within a strongly typed view is meeting pretty much all of my requirements.  But thanks again.

Comment: And MVC Contrib has a concept of portal areas which I am looking into but first I am creating own version of a completely async data grid with code to dynamically modify linq expression.